# PHP - get datetime when jpg file at URL has been accessed last time

Tags: php, time, url

I know the date-time is saved in the access log, but I think its not possible to read this file from php.
What is the easiest way to find out the date and time when a specific file (jpg) has been last accessed / downloaded from my website? The file itself is NOT displayed in a html/php script. I mean direct access to it like https://www.orf.at/image1.jpg

Comment: This is more a question for stackoverflow.  You are looking for the "atime" field in the result from "stat"  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

Comment: Well, no sorry stat does not do the trick. It does not change the time when I only access the file from my browser (even when I change the browser, no cache problem)

Comment: It is possible that the file system was mounted with `noatime` setting.  This would mean that there's simply no record of the file being accessed.  Your only remaining option would be to trawl access logs or place a (php?) wrapper around the file to record access.